# Silencing "guessed channel layout" for FFmpeg

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

Does anyone know what parameters I can run FFmpeg under to silence console messages about guessing channel layouts for input streams?

Answer (score 3):

That message is a warning. To suppress all warnings, the loglevel should be `< 24`, so e.g. `ffmpeg -v 16 -i in.wav out.mp3`.

You can also disable performing the action of guessing (not just its announcement) by the input option of `-guess_layout_max` i.e. `ffmpeg -guess_layout_max 0 -i in.wav out.mp3`. The issue with this is that the output won't be flagged with a channel layout. You can correct this by explicitly setting output channels option `-ac N` where N is the number of channels in the output.

Comment: that like -ac N, incredible i'd been trying to problem solve that for hours!